# google maps api utility v3 styled markers, bigger markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to style my markers, is there a way to change size of the marker?

```
            var marker = new StyledMarker({
                styleIcon: new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER,{color:"#82F56D", text:''+i+''}),
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: label,
                zIndex: z
            });
```

This is my code for the styledmarker in the google maps utility library. How do I make the bubbles bigger on the rounding part? My numbers are to close to the edges. I'd like to have some kind of padding or some sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/docs/reference.html) there is no such thing as a size property
or anything related to manipulate the size